# Why NSObject Class can not comply the UITableViewDataSource Protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a class inherited from NSObject, and comply the UITableViewDataSource. it will service my tableView. But than i got this:

[image]
can any one tell me why it happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import `UIKit` Framework. `UITableView` & its `protocols` are part of `UIKit framework`.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

UIKit protocols are under the <UIKit/UIKit.h> umbrella header, not the <Foundation/Foundation.h> umbrella header.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewDataSource` is a part of the UIKit framework which must be imported

`@import UIKit;`

will do the trick. UIKit already imports the Foundation framework so

`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` is no longer necessary